# access method in object from arraylist

Tags: java

I have a ArrayList of objects which stored either a ForSaleProperty object or RentalProperty object;

```
static ArrayList<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

My RentalProperty and a ForSaleProperty is subclass of Property

```
RentalProperty extends Property 
ForSaleProperty extends Property
```

Inside Property, I have an Address and ViewingArrangement object.

In ViewingArrangement, i have a ContactPerson object an a String openTime variable. I also have the method setOpenTime in ViewingArrangement.

Problem :

How do i access the setOpenTime() method in ViewingArrangement.

In my Object arraylist, i have this

```
RentalProperty rp1 = new RentalProperty(1500,"6-Jun-16");
Address a1 = new Address(150,"Tampines Ave 5","Singapore",6002);
ContactPerson cp1 = new ContactPerson("Benjamin","Murdoch",2738482);
ViewingArrangement va1 = new ViewingArrangement(cp1,"1000H");
rp1.setAddress(a1);
rp1.setVA(va1);

obj.add(rp1);
```

So now i want to change the openTime of rp1.

I tried the following but cant access the method in my object.

```
static void editOpenTime()
{
    int input;
    String newOpenTime;
     listProperty();
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter property number : ");
     input = in.nextInt(); in.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Enter new open time for property # : "+input);
     newOpenTime = in.nextLine();

     obj.get(input).

}
```

Comment: i cant seems to the list of methods. Do i have to static the methods?    

public void setTime(String time)
    {
        this.time = time;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it is better to use a type that is not Object if possible for type safety. In your case use Property since both extend that.

```
static ArrayList<Property> properties = new ArrayList<Property>();
```

Then you can get the VA like follows:

```
ViewingArrangement va = properties.get(input).getVA();
va.setOpenTime()
```

Comment: thanks!! it worked!